# Show namespace of a class in Quick Documentation

Tags: c#, namespaces, rider

Quick Documentation by default looks like this:

[image]
It only shows the class name (Extensions) without the namespace. I know I can click on the class name to see the namespace, but is there any option to directly display the namespace along the class name?